# Duplicate first column of csv using command line [edited]

Tags: csv, text, replace

I'm trying to duplicate and prepend the first column of a csv with a date from Windows command line.

I've tried powershell -replace with RegEx and For /f but I can't get it.

Example simplified CSV:

col a, col b
IE00abcdefgh,text
IE00defghijk,text

Column A always starts with IE00 and then 8 more random characters.

Desired Output:

newcol, col a ,col b
20200428-IE00abcdefgh,IE00abcdefgh,text
20200428-IE00defghijk,IE00defghijk,text

I already have the date to prepend in a %%date%% variable.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Powershell available, this is one way to accomplish.

**dataInput.csv**

```
col a, col b
IE00abcdefgh,text
IE00defghijk,text
```

**prependDate.ps1**

```
$a = import-csv -path .\dataInput.csv

$newcol = "newcol, col a, col b`n"

foreach ($row in $a){
    $newcol += ((get-date -Format "yyyyMMdd-")+$row."col a"+","+$row."col a"+","+$row."col b"+"`n")
}

$newcol | out-file -filepath newOutput.csv
```

**newOutput.csv**

```
newcol, col a, col b
20200509-IE00abcdefgh,IE00abcdefgh,text
20200509-IE00defghijk,IE00defghijk,text
```

And on Windows cmd call for the file

```
powershell.exe -f prependDate.ps1
```